# How to spend ERC20 tokens where ETH is required?

Tags: erc-20

As in the title. How do i spend erc20 tokens in the same way that i would ethereum? they are interchangeable right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC20 tokens are contracts that run on the Ethereum blockchain which functions on the use of **ETH**. This does not mean there are **directly** interchangeable.

The idea here is *'exchange'* rather than *'interchange'*.